# How to get absolute path from UNC path in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have shared folders on my local computer. After I am trying to browse that shared folders from Server. But it returns me a UNC path, How can I get absolute path from UNC path? 
Example

**\CompName\music**

I need

**/Users/user/desktop/music**

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What Objective-C API are you using that gives you a UNC path?

Comment: I don't use any API. I am just creating share using dscl , and send UNC path to server. I am creating UNC path by hand. But after I am getting all the UNC path, I need to determine their local paths

Comment: The dscl tool is typically invoked from the command line.  I'd recommend taking out the inaccurate "objective-c" and "cocoa" tags here and adding in "shell-scripting" instead.

Comment: I need to get Absolute path from UNC path, in OBjective -C. That is my questions